# How to get the Default value of Dropdown when loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and it has only one value for time being. So I am not able to use:

```
  $('#dropDown1').change
```

But what I want to do is get the default value and pass this to another jquery function.

I tried using  `$('#dropDown1').click`  but not what I am looking at .

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this:

**Html:**

```
<select id="dropDown1">
<option value="1">One</option
</select>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var val = $('#dropDown1').val();

});
```

Comment: But in which event? I want to pass that to another method as soon as value gets updated

Comment: Since dropdown1 is getting updated by a REST service , document.ready is not able get the value at that point.

Comment: you are calling service via ajax, so you can use use its success function for this puropse, but you have not mentioned in post that it is being created from response of Rest Service